# connect revolute to motor in simscape

Tags: matlab, simscape, simmechanics

I have imported system to simscape using simmechanics, this is the system ... [image]

I want to control the system with real dc motor so I want to connect the revolute with dc motor

I tried to connect it with dc motor with specified no load speed and stall torque

This is parameters for motor block [image]

And then sensed the torque and connected it to recolute like this [image]

That worked but, the speed of the revolute is more than no-load speed of the motor, and toque is not affected by the load

Is there better solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, the following answer has what you're looking for:

[Adding a DC Motor to a Simscape Multibody Revolute Joint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41980454/adding-a-dc-motor-to-a-simscape-multibody-revolute-joint)

The way to do it is to sense the speed of the revolute joint and feed it to the motor network with an ideal velocity source block. At the same time, sense the torque computed with a torque sensor and feed the output to the revolute joint. You can find an example of this (ready to copy/paste) in:

sm_bread_slicer

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)